# Irregular behaviour of celery

Tags: python, django, cron, celery, celerybeat

I am very new to **Celery** and I am trying to use it to schedule a function, but its not working properly it seems.
Here is my `settings.py:` (Along with the default settings given by django)

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///results.sqlite'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

`celery.py:`

```
rom __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mera_project.settings')

app = Celery('mera_project')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

`init.py:`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

`tasks_notes/tasks.py:`(tasks_notes is my app name)

```
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from tasks_notes.models import BudgetInfo

@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/15')))
def monthly_starting_value():
    print("hi")
    return 0
```

`views.py:`

```
from .tasks import monthly_starting_value
def app_view(request):
   abcd = monthly_starting_value.delay()
    print("new"+str(abcd))
```

I had expected value **zero** and **hi** in my terminal, but instead of that I have got a random number as **new 42bf83ef-850f-4b34-af78-da696d2ee0f2** and the random number keeps on changing in every 15 minutes.
In my ``celery beat``` running terminal tab, I am getting something like:

```
WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] hi
Task tasks_notes.tasks.monthly_starting_value[42bf83ef-850f-4b34-af78-da696d2ee0f2] succeeded in 0.0009442089994990965s: 0
```

in every 15 minutes.
I have even tried ``app.beat.conf_schedule`in`celery.py``` and also tried running in admin phase, but its not working as expected.

Where can I be wrong?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not irregular - it behaves exactly as it should.
If you wanted to grab the result of a task, then you should have something like:

```
abcd = monthly_starting_value.delay().get()
```

delay() returns an instance of AsyncResult class.

Finally, do not call print() inside task. Use the Celery logger.

Example:

```
import os
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from worker import app

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@app.task()
def add(x, y):
    result = x + y
    logger.info(f'Add: {x} + {y} = {result}')
    return result
```

Comment: This time ``print(str(abcd))`` is printing **None** and I have removed the ``print`` function from ``tasks.py`` and returning the value of variable ``var=6``. What might be the issue?